# htaccess - 301 redirecting specific file and extension to folder root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

So astonishingly I can't find this answered anywhere (in a simple manner anyway).

I'm looking to redirect some old URLs on a site to the new structure. Problem is - with my ability, I am running in to problems.

What I'd like:

To redirect `/oldfolder/example.html` to `http://website.com/newfolder/`

So I'm using this:

```
Redirect 301 /oldfolder/example.html http://website.com/newfolder/
```

Problem is, this seems to end up redirecting to:
`http://website.com/newfolder/example.html`

And I can't seem to stop it appending the old file name `/example.html` on the end of the new URL.

I've also tried:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldfolder/example.html$ http://website.com/newfolder/$
```

But still no luck.

Can anyone help me get the right syntax to redirect from a file, to a different folder root please?

EDIT:
Since the solution in the first answer below didn't seem to help, I get the feeling there is more to it, so here is some more info...

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# WORKING
Redirect 301 /defaultsite http://improvemyrunning.com/
Redirect 301 /book/index.html http://improvemyrunning.com/
Redirect 301 /contact/index.html http://improvemyrunning.com/contact/
Redirect 301 /camps/ http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/ http://improvemyrunning.com/
Redirect 301 /assets/neil_feedback.pdf http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /team/index.html http://improvemyrunning.com/about/
Redirect 301 /coaching/index.html http://improvemyrunning.com/services/


# BROKEN
Redirect 301 /camps/feedback.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /camps/itinerary.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/index.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/index2.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/1.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/2.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/3.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/4.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/5.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/6.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/7.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/8.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/9.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/10.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/11.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/12.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/13.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/14.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/15.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/16.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Glenholm%20Countryside/slides/17.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Run%20Training%20Camp%20September%202013/index.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Run%20Training%20Camp%20September%202013/slides/Glenholm_Centre.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Run%20Training%20Camp%20September%202013/slides/Group_Picture.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Run%20Training%20Camp%20September%202013/slides/Beautiful_Weather.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/
Redirect 301 /photos/Run%20Training%20Camp%20September%202013/slides/Sunday_Trail_Running.html http://improvemyrunning.com/run-camps/


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can anybody see anything I'm missing? Perhaps the Wordpress htaccess rules at the bottom are interfering??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldfolder/example\.html$ /newfolder/
```

Make sure to test it out in a new browser to avoid old 301 browser cache.

If you are using `mod_rewrite` then you can use this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^oldfolder/example\.html$ /newfolder/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Many thanks, I believe there must be more to my problem, since either of these solutions are working. I will elaborate on my initial question.

Comment: I have added my htaccess file - something is telling that perhaps the Wordpress rules are interfering...

Comment: Which URL didn't redirect. I would suggest using `mod_rewrite` rules only so don't use `Redirect` rules.

Comment: The rules below `# BROKEN` in my htaccess file are failing to behave as predicted :/

Comment: First thing first delete all `Redirect 301` lines from your .htaccess and then add my suggested `RewriteRule` line just below `RewriteBase` line.